# toLowerCase, arrays, Object.keys, find, and Flow syntax

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Having some problems with getting Flow syntax going on this correctly.

Given this object:

```
const objStr = {
  A: 1,
  B: 2,
  C: 3
};
```

And this assignment:

```
const key = Object.keys(objStr).find((key) => objStr[key] === 2).toLowerCase();
// key === 'b'
```

I get this error from Flow:

```
Cannot call `Object.keys(...).find(...).toLowerCase` because property `toLowerCase` is missing in  undefined [1].Flow(InferError)
```

Not sure how to configure the right annotations to resolve this.

Comment: Never used flow, but I bet the issue is that `.find` may return `undefined`, so you need to check to see if the result is defined first.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yeah I suspect that's it.

Comment: With the given data, the code is working perfectly. Just the issue is if `.find` returns undefined, then you are not handling it. `undefined.toLowerCase()` will throw error. Try to check the type of result first before converting it to lowercase.

Comment: @Rajesh Do you mean the return value when nothing is found is `null`, not `undefined`? `[].find(_ => false)` gives me `undefined`, not `null`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm guessing that's the type signature in Flow. And I also suspect Flow conflates `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance My Bad! I could have sworn that I have received null values for non-matching conditions, but [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Syntax) says `undefined`.

Comment: Is there a way to tell flow that `Object.find` will always return a particular type of value and never `undefined`?

Comment: @Geuis try `(Object.keys(objStr).find((key) => objStr[key] === 5) || '').toLowerCase();`

Comment: @User863 hey that did it! Thanks!

Comment: @User863 you should un-delete your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Logical OR operator (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) for falsy values like `undefined`

```js
const objStr = {
  A: 1,
  B: 2,
  C: 3
}

const key = (Object.keys(objStr).find((key) => objStr[key] === 5) || '').toLowerCase()

console.log(key)
```